# JFreechart: Preventing truncation in bubble charts

Tags: jfreechart

I'm writing an automatic report generator that visualizes three-way evaluations as coordinate graphics, where the circle size expresses the third value as a kind of virtual Z coordinate. It works fine, but when a top-rated item is displayed near the edge, its circle may be cut off, like this:

[image: three bubbles dran with JFreeChart]

I'd like to extend the chart so that the entire circle is drawn, but the axes shouldn't get labels above 10 (the evaluation allowed choices 1-10, and it would be misleading to pretend that 11 was an option). How can I extend the `ValueAxis` farther up and right, but without more ticks? Or how can I extend the entire chart space, but without extending the X and Y axes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing a larger percentage to [`setUpperMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setUpperMargin-double-); this fragment specifies 20%.

```
XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyplot.getDomainAxis();
domain.setUpperMargin(1/5d);
NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyplot.getRangeAxis();
range.setUpperMargin(1/5d);
```